# Scala Binary tree, setting next "node" when navigating

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, binary-tree, covariance

I have a binary tree. I ask a user a question, if he says yes, I give him left branch, otherwise I give him right branch.  (method: get_answer2)

But when I do this:

```
var current_node = Node("Test")
current_node.set_left = Node("End node")
current_node = current_node.get_answer2("y")
```

I get

Expression of type Tree[Nothing] does not conform to to expected type Tree[Nothing] (from IntelliJ)

```
sealed abstract class Tree[+T] {
}
case object End extends Tree[Nothing] {
  var left = "Blah"
  var right = "Blah"

  override def toString = "."
}

case class Node[T](var question: String,  var left: Tree[T] = End, var right: Tree[T] = End) extends Tree[T] {

  def get_answer2(answer: String) ={
    if (answer == "y"){
      right
    }else{
      left
    }
  }

  def change_left_tree( new_tree : Tree[T]) = {left = new_tree}
  def change_right_tree( new_tree : Tree[T]) = {right = new_tree}
}
```

Comment: no = left, (not right as you mention)

Answer (score 0):

Sugested solution:

```
var current_node = Node("Test")
current_node.left = Node("End node")
var answer = current_node.get_answer2("n")
answer match {
    case End => {
        println("Empty")
        }
    case x: Node[_] => {
        println("Node")
        current_node = x
        println(current_node)
    }
}
```

Problem with your code was that variable 'left' is declared as Tree. And Tree is broader type then Node. To compiler it doesn't matter that object assigned to variable 'left' is of type 'Node'.

In my solution var 'answer' is of type 'Tree'. To cast it to type 'Node' I used 'match' construction with two cases (first for empty nodes and second for not-empty)

Comment: how can i change it to make it not a Tree?  I am trying to traverse over the binary tree via loop, hence, I a need to set current_node  to whichever node I am on.